# Организация юнит тестов, изолирование зависимостей

Tags: qt, юнит-тесты

Доброго времени суток!
Постигаю азы тестирования в связи с этим возникли некоторые вопросы..
Например, есть проект А, возникла необходимость протестировать класс foo, в результате чего проект приобрел следующую структуру:

```
-src
    -main.cpp
    -foo.h
    -foo.cpp
    -bar.h
    -baz.h
    -...
-tests
    -main.cpp
    -tst_foo.h
    -mockbar.h
    -mockbaz.h
    -...
```

Т.к. нас интересует только foo, который зависит от bar и  baz необходимо создать stub/mock/fake/..(в данном случае неважно) objects.

1. Я правильно понимаю, что в данном случае просто берется объектный файл foo (например, полученный при сборке основного проекта), линкуется с моками, тестами (в случае с Qt еще и с moc_foo) и.. все? Это и есть правильный подход в организации юнит тестов?
2. Однако, у меня ситуация несколько иная: bar и baz имею в заголовках еще несколько зависимостей и чтобы не писать еще и для них "фейковые" классы можно затянуть в тестовый подпроект не объектник, а исходники класса foo, скомпилить их с "фейковыми" классами у которых этих инклудов попросту нет и тестировать. Но как то "кастыльно" это смотрится.. Правильно ли я понимаю, что в данном случае проблема в архитектуре и надо приводить код к ситуации №1 ?

Comment: Правильный подход - сначала всегда писать модульные тесты. И опираться на инверсию зависимостей при реализации классов. Классы не должны зависеть от конкретных реализаций. Для обеспечения слабой связанности, которая в свою очередь обеспечивает возможность тестирования, необходимо в качестве зависимостей использовать абстрактные классы. А в тестах например использовать реализации этих абстрактных классов, имитирующие необходимое для успешного выполнения теста поведение.